# While with the present simple meaning an on-going action

Tags: present-tense

I was told that this is grammatically correct.

(A conversation over the phone)

> - What are you doing now?
> - I am having a good time while I go to my granny's.

I was told that "while I go to my granny's" means "while I am going to".

Do you think it's correct?

**Extra examples**:

1. Buy me a drink while I go to the rest room.

2.'You are tired,' he said, 'and **while I sit**, you walk about. Have my chair. 'He placed himself between Griffin and the nearest window.

3. Shut up, I'm talking, finish eating **while I speak** and then you will be able to say what you want.

Comment: In response to your previous question you were told that 'going to grandma's' referred to the whole visit. However, this rather oddly expressed statement does sound as though it refers to the journey - 'while I am travelling there'. Was the person a native speaker of English?

Comment: Yes, american...

Comment: In (2) and (3) the action is ongoing. In (1), _go_ obviously refers to the whole incident (going there, doing what's necessary and coming back).

Comment: This is what the person (american said) about the original sentence - is OK to say on the phone to someone while you are en route.